# Process builder on asset not populating asset id in newly created case(immediate action)

Tags: formula, process-builder, case, asset

I am firing a process builder on Asset. In immediate action I am creating a Case. Now I have a lookup from Case to Asset, I am stamping the AssetId on the Case Lookup field. But this is not being Populated.

I am using the formula 
Chiller Asset Reference Asset.Id

Can anyone tell me where am I going wrong. I assume that the Case will be created only after the Asset is Created. So the case should have access to the Asset Id. Can anyone tell me where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It is working for me. Attached is the screenshot of working process builder -
[image]